# Reduce mp4 size to send through email

Tags: ffmpeg, compression, video-editor

I could not send a mp4 using Yahoo! mail because it took around 30 minutes.

On Ubuntu MATE 18.04, I reduced the size using `ffmpeg`.

```bsh
ffmpeg -i sm_Julia1.mpr -s hd480 -strict -2  output.mp4
```

But the file was still too big.

Is there another option?

Comment: You can make a video as small as you want. The smaller you make it, the less you will see on it.

Comment: @llogan size limit for yahoo mail is 25 Mb.

Comment: 72 seconds. @llogan

Answer (score 4):

split the file using zip:

```
$ zip -s 100m archive.zip output.mp4
```

And reassemble with:

```
$ zip -s 0 archive.zip --out output.zip
```

Last unzip the archive:

```
$ unzip output.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the file duration (72 seconds) you can use two-pass encoding to output approximately your desired output file size (25 MB). From [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264 - Two-Pass](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#twopass):

```
(25 MiB * 8192 [converts MiB to kBit]) / 72 seconds = ~2844 kBit/s total bitrate
2844 kBit/s - 128 kBit/s (desired audio bitrate) = 2716 kBit/s video bitrate - 5% safety margin = 2580 kBit/s
```

So use `-b:v 2580k`:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -an -pass 1 -b:v 2580k -f mp4 /dev/null && ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -b:v 2580k -b:a 128k -pass 2 -movflags faststart output.mp4
```

Result ≈ 24 MB.